# CollapsiblePanel Hovering Over Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Is there a way to have an AJAX CollapsiblePanel drop down and hover over the other elements on the page without resizing things?

Right now, I have:

```
<asp:Button ID="TriggerButton" runat="server" />
<asp:Panel ID="CollapsiblePanel" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
<asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="CollapsiblePanel" Collapsed="true" AutoCollapse="false" AutoExpand="false" ExpandControlID="TriggerButton" CollapseControlID="TriggerButton">
</asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box there is no option as far as I am aware but I'd make a guess you could probably do something by using css and setting the z index of the panel and surrounding controls .. my css isn't great though when it comes to positioning so sorry I can't give any examples.

EDIT:

Try this: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_23761881.html
(if you don't have a experts exchange membership scroll right to the bottom of the page and the answer is displayed!)

Comment: @Carl You put me on a mission.. I was sure it was possible so I did a bit of searching! I have edited my post above.

Comment: Thanks very much!  So to summarize: The way do it is to wrap the panel and the extending button in a div that has a "position:absolute".